# How to migrate data from other CMS to Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

There are a million records in our old CMS system. Now we want to migrate the old data to Wagtail. How to import these data? I know I have to create a model to store the data, but how to import the records to the model tables in Wagtail? Should I insert these records into the MySql database immediately? Or use some APIs or functions of wagtail?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411849/5548239.  Django's `inspectdb` will give you a head start on creating models for the old database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't think that inspected is what I am looking for. We want to create a new model to handle these. I just want to create a new model in Wagtail, then import the old data by some scripts. Perhaps I can insert these records into the model table, but how to update the ES index? I just want to use Elasticsearch as my search engine.

Answer (score 3):

I have taken the following approach several times when migrating complicated Drupal sites to Wagtail:

1. Export the legacy content in some format that I can easily manipulate with python. (The Drupal sites I worked with generated CSV exports, but you could just as easily work with JSON or XML; whatever you can get your old system to spit out.)
2. Write a Django [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) that parses your export and creates Wagtail page objects. I found [these instructions](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-add-wagtail-page-programmatically-via-python-script/) helpful, though at 
   step 4 I do `page.save_revision().publish()` instead of just `page.save()`.

You've got a lot more records than I ever dealt with, so perhaps you'd find it easier to skip step 1 and query your old db directly in the management command.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want.